# SQLiteDatabase AUTO INCREMENT null

Tags: android

I have that query

```
"CREATE TABLE CAdres (id INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT,CariID INTEGER, No INTEGER, Adres TEXT,Tel TEXT,Fax TEXT, NotTanim TEXT,PRIMARY KEY (CariID, No));"
```

when i inside record , id is null . why null ? normal sql increment number but sqlite come "null".

Comment: My database image http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ih0c20&s=8#.VE4Hpfl_vts

Answer (score 3):

To get an autoincrementing id column, the column type must be

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

or

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Your id column `INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT` is just a regular column which can store NULLs. The `AUTO` and `INCREMENT` are not keywords and don't affect anything.

You can also have only one primary key per table so remove the

```
,PRIMARY KEY (CariID, No)
```

If you need the combination to be unique, you can change that to a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: İ dont need id primary key , my primary key PRIMARY KEY (CariID, No). Only need id autoıncrement work. My database picture http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ih0c20&s=8#.VE4Hpfl_vts

Comment: You cannot have an autoincrementing column without it being the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. it may work..

```
"CREATE TABLE CAdres (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CariID INTEGER NOT NULL, No INTEGER NOT NULL, Adres TEXT,Tel TEXT,Fax TEXT, NotTanim TEXT ,UNIQUE (CariID, No));"
```

note : diff between primary key and unique is that , unique can be null and primary key cannot be null..

Comment: Thanks,maybe  this is other way solitions.